# How do I add a confirmation dialog to the Wordpress publish button?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin which creates a custom post type "knowledgebase article" with some special fields. I'd like the publish button to warn the user if they are missing fields before they commit. How do I do this? Is there an appropriate hook to insert this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the basic client-side form validation script in `wp-admin/js/common.js` which is included by default on all admin pages.

First, add an action via your plugin that runs on the post editing screen:

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_validation_script');
function my_validation_script() {
    global $post_type;
    if(isset($post_type) && $post_type == 'knowledgebase_article') {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-validation-script', network_site_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-folder/my-validation-script.js', array('jquery', 'common'));
    }
}
```

Next, write the little javascript form handler to actually handle the form submission:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //'my_required_field' is the class name of the DIV or TD tag *containing* the required form field
    jQuery('.my_required_field').addClass('form-required'); 

    //'post' is the ID of the main form on the new post screen
    jQuery('#post').submit(function(){ 
            //the validateForm function lives in wp-admin/js/common.js
            if ( !validateForm( jQuery(this)) ) { 
                    alert('Please enter a value'); 
                    return false; //stop submitting the form
            } else {
                    //alert('all required fields have some input');
            }
    });

});
```

You can see how this validator behaves by visiting the tag editing page, then creating a new tag with no name.  The field's container turns red alerting you to the problem.

I tested this on my end and it works.  Hopefully it can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll give it a shot when I get into the office on Monday. :-)

Comment: This solution was spot on. I don't know why my question was closed for being 'vague', you understood exactly what I was asking.

Comment: I wondered the same thing about the 'vague'ness.  Thanks for the +1